# Authorize attribute always returns 401

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using client credential/app identity flow (OAuth 2.0) where the API is able to authenticate the web app by its app id. There are 2 things that I need to make sure the authentication is successful:

1. The access token passed from web app to access the API should be a valid bearer token (eg: not expired, valid format, etc)
2. The app id from the access token has to be the specified web app

**When I put the [authorize] attribute in the controller class, it kept returning 401.**

Here is startup.cs class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtentsions class

```
public static class AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtentsions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddAzureAdBearer(_ => { });

        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
            builder.AddJwtBearer();
            return builder;
        }

        private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
        {
            private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

            public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
            {
                _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
            }

            public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new string[] {
                        _azureOptions.ClientId,
                        _azureOptions.ClientIdUrl
                    },
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = true
                };
                options.Audience = _azureOptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
            }

            public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's AzureAdOptions class

```
 public class AzureAdOptions
    {
        internal static readonly object Settings;

        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public string ClientIdUrl { get; set; }

        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }

        public string Instance { get; set; }

        public string Domain { get; set; }

        public string TenantId { get; set; }
    }
```

And controller class

```
  [Route("api")]
    [ApiController]
public class FindController : ControllerBase
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    HttpClient _client;
    public ContentController( IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    private bool ValidateRequest()
    {
        var authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader) || authHeader.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(Messages.AuthHeaderIsRequired);
        }
        var tokenWithBearer = authHeader.Single();
        var token = tokenWithBearer.Substring(7); //remove bearer in the token
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        if (!jwtHandler.CanReadToken(token))
        {
            throw new FormatException("Invalid JWT Token");
        }

        var tokenS = jwtHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
        var appId = tokenS.Audiences.First();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appId))
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(Messages.AppIdIsMissing);
        }
        var registeredAppId = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd:AuthorizedApplicationIdList")?.Get<List<string>>();
        return (registeredAppId.Contains(appId)) ? true : false;
    }
    [HttpPost("Find")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Find()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ValidateRequest())
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
         return new ObjectResult("hello world!");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows why it keeps returning 401 error? One thing I would like to mention is between the time I start calling the API till it returns 401 error, the break points inside the controller class never got hit...

Comment: You may post related code for how do you get the access token , using AAD V1.0 or v2.0 ?

Comment: yes, i realized the way i generated the access token is not correct. I found a tutorial here but currently have trouble generating the token: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252940/aadsts90002-tenant-xx-not-found-this-may-happen-if-there-are-no-active-subsc

Comment: @NanYu The access token is now generated correctly. Thanks for your help. But still the api is returning 401 with the `[Authorize]` attribute in the controller class. No breakpoints were hit in `controller` class and `AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtentsions` class. Any idea why?

Comment: What is your _azureOptions.ClientId ? The api application's client id ?

Comment: `_azureOptions.ClientId` is the app id from my target app.

Comment: Let me confirm that you put API application's app id / app id url as valid audience ,not your client app's app id ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190341/discussion-between-ww-pana-and-nan-yu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resource is `App ID URI` of the api application when acquiring access token for accessing api application . In api application , allowed audience should also include the `App ID URI` of the api application .

Answer (score 1):

I would make 2 points for you to check:

**1. Check for appID matching AuthorizedApplicationIdList in your code**

I think the way you have described conditions to check in words is fine, but there is a problem with how you have implemented the second condition in code.

> 2. The app id from the access token has to be the specified web app

When implementing this condition, it seems you are setting appId as the value from `aud` i.e. audience claim in token. This is incorrect, because audience will always be your own API for which this token is intended.

What you want to check instead is the value for `appid` claim in token, which will be the application ID for client that acquired this token. This should be the front end web app's application ID which you want to check against your list of Authorized applications.

Take a look at [Microsoft Docs reference for Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens)

[image]

[image]

Also, you can verify this easily by decoding the token using https://jwt.ms

**Relevant code from your post where I see issue**:

```
    var appId = tokenS.Audiences.First();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appId))
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(Messages.AppIdIsMissing);
    }
    var registeredAppId = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd:AuthorizedApplicationIdList")?.Get<List<string>>();
    return (registeredAppId.Contains(appId)) ? true : false;
```

**2. General Log/Debug**

Also, on a side note, you can probably debug or put log/trace statements in your API code to find out exactly where it's failing in your code.. or if it unexpectedly fails somewhere even before your custom logic is called. Maybe while some of the initial validations are being performed.

Comment: hmm, actually the tokenS is coming from web app. Therefore the audiences will be the web app's app id, not my API's app id.

Comment: @WWpana I have updated the answer to include reference for Access tokens from Microsoft Docs to show the description for both claims `aud` and `appid`.. I would still say the audience will be App ID URI for your web API.. and the `appid` will be application ID for your frontend web app which acquired the token.. A good way to check this will be to decode the token in https://jwt.ms My understanding is that web app acquires the access token FOR web API.. and as the access token is meant for web API, that's what `aud` claim or intended audience tells

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. For your second point, I tried to debug but it never hit any of my break points in the controller class or anywhere in the solution.. Do you know what could cause this issue?

Comment: @WWpana the initial configuration code where you have TokenValidationParameters would be another area to check.. not sure if you have breakpoints/log statements there..

Comment: `appid` doesn't seem to exist in OAuth2.0 token anymore. I'm assuming `oid` be the alternative?

Comment: @WWpana `azp` claim would be the alternative. You might be using v2.0 endpoint. For tokens from v1 endpoint `appid` claim will give the application ID and in case of v2 endpoint `azp` will do the same. `oid` is a different claim which represents object Id