# AADSTS90002: Tenant 'xx' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I followed [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/03/17/accessing-azure-app-services-using-azure-ad-bearer-token-2/) tutorial to generate an access token from client app for target app. According to the comment for this tutorial, for the `resources`, I changed to App ID URL. But I am still not able to successfully generate bearer token for the target app.

It shows this error message:

> AdalException:
>   {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90002: Tenant
>   '' not found. This may happen if there are no active
>   subscriptions for the tenant....}

Anyone knows what else I missed?

Comment: **1)** As the error says, make sure you're using the correct tenantId or name like xyz.onmicrosoft.com especially when specifying `authority` share the authority value you're using here if possible (remove any sensitive info) **2)** tutorial is a little old, what version of ADAL `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` are you using? **3)** How did you register you application? Azure portal `https://portal.azure.com` or `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/`

Comment: to answer your questions, `1)` the authority is correct `2)` 4.5.1 `3)` https://portal.azure.com

Comment: ok makes sense.. for `resource` when you say you're using App ID URL.. where did you get it from? Ideally it should be the App ID URI value for target app that you're acquiring token for.. to get the value go to Azure Portal > Azure AD > target app registration  > Settings > Properties and you should see App ID URI there.. value should exactly match.. Also, just to confirm, you're getting that error when `context.AcquireTokenAsync(
                resource,  clientCredential);` is getting executed?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i entered the wrong App ID URI from the client app..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ADAL to get access token using client credential flow :

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =
       new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>");

ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
AuthenticationResult result =
       await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://resourceUrl",
                                                         clientCredential);
```

Reference : https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows

And document : [Service to service calls using client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)

Comment: Do you set the correct tenant id or name ? To find your tenant id , click Azure Active Directory -->Properties-->Directory ID

Comment: @WWpana Also try this :            string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
            string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Instance, "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com");

            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =
 new AuthenticationContext(authority);

Comment: I got it working! I entered the wrong tenant id :( thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

For me the issue was resolved by using older version of **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory**.
I had to used 3.13.8 version. Latest version has issues.

Comment: You are a saviour!!

Comment: Still the case in November 2020!

Comment: This fix is still applicable in March 2021

Answer (score 0):

In my case I mistakened the client Id (a string that looks like `xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx`) with the tenant Id (a string that looks like `myproject.onmicrosoft.com`)

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer ? tenantID